# jQuery Validation Engine not working, getting the message: is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

This is my code :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validation/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validation/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            $(".register_form").validationEngine();

            $(".register_form").bind("jqv.field.result", function(event, field, errorFound, prompText){
                console.log(errorFound) ;
            });
        });
</script>

    <form id="contact-form" action ="<?php echo $this->basePath()."/user/register" ?>" method ="post"  name="register_form" class="register_form">
                    <div class ="col-md-6">
                        <div class="text-fields">
                            <div class="float-input">
                                <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class ="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20]] text-input"  placeholder="username"  >
                                <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="contact-submit" id="register_submit">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                Register
                    </button>
    </form>
```

As you see i have just one input text field (username). but when i load the page in the console i get this error message : 
**

```
TypeError: $(...).validationEngine is not a function
$(".register_form").validationEngine();
```

**

WHY ? I already check multiple post from stackoverflow, which have related question, but non of them is working for me

Comment: Can you confirm by looking into the browser's console that there are no 404s while loading the relative references to the js files ? (hint- you might have to get rid of the leading `/` in the path)

Comment: it is not 404, im getting code, i believe there is some conflict with another version of jquery that i have , is there a way to keep all of the jquery version ?\

Comment: Please dont do that. The code becomes unmaintainable. It is a better idea to do it the clean way. If you already have jquery loaded, why not use that? Just remove this reference of jquery - from the looks of it, jquery does not seem to be the issue - it is the validation libraries.

Comment: There demos have jquery version jquery-1.6.min.js... check if they are compatible with 1.11.2............... http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery-1.6.min.js

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validation/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validation/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
```

I believe you shouldn't have those leading slashes at the beginning :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
```

The path is thus wrong and the library not loaded. You then call a function/method that has not been defined.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I noticed this error only surfaces when validating radio buttons or checkboxes as follows:

```
<input id="level1" class="validate[required] radio" name="level" value="1" type="radio">
<input id="level2" class="validate[required] radio" name="level" value="2" type="radio">
<input id="level3" class="validate[required] radio" name="level" value="3" type="radio">
```

remove that or correct these to continue.